# What's the best way to include CSS for JS-enabled browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What's the best practice way to include a CSS file in your HTML page on JS-enabled browsers only? I heard that using document.write is highly discouraged.

```html
<head>
  <!-- Other head stuff here -->
  <script>document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/layout_js-only.css">');</script>
</head>
```

Comment: CSS is supposed to be loaded before the <body>, and the only way to do that dynamically is via document.write(). a plain DOM link tag addition to <head> might be a little more philosophically cleaner JS-wise, but it will also be async, which can cause a FAUC. really the best way (balancing theory and real-world) is to hard-code any sheets you'll need as <link> tags in the <head> and then disable/un-disable certain ones via JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would a solution like this be what you are looking for:
[Use some CSS only if user has JavaScript enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779401/use-some-css-only-if-user-has-javascript-enabled)

Basically, set a class on the body tag of "noJS". Then use Javascript to remove that class.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely [don't use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice). You can do the same work as `document.write` by creating new elements and appending them to the `<head>`.

```
var stylesheet = document.createElement('link');
stylesheet.rel = 'stylesheet';
stylesheet.href = 'assets/stylesheets/layout_js-only.css';
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(stylesheet);
```

I'd also suggest placing this code in the `<body>` to ensure the `<head>` is properly loaded.

Comment: adding css from the body, and adding it async, are both ways of ensuring a FOUC...

Comment: @dandavis True. Ideally you don't add CSS files dynamically but if you want to, this is a good way to do it.